# loop to sum array returns address like reading instead of the correct answer. why?

Tags: forth, gforth

I'm trying to make a program that will sum an array for me, but it keeps on giving me a really long number resembling an address when I try to run the word sum. I tried taking it apart and running it line by line outside of the word in the terminal and manually looping worked fine, but it totally fails when I go to actually make it work. what am i doing wrong?

```
variable length \ length var declared
create list \ space for my list made
0 variable cumsum  \ sum value initialized to zero

: upload     ( n1 n2 n3 --) \ loops thru and stuffs data into array
depth        ( n1 n2 n3 -- n1 n2 n3 depth) \ get depth
length !     ( n1 n2 n3 depth -- n1 n2 n3) \ array length stored
list         ( n1 n2 n3 -- n1 n2 n3 addr)
length @     ( n1 n2 n3 addr -- n1 n2 n3 addr nlength)
cells allot  ( n1 n2 n3 addr nlength -- n1 n2 n3) 
length @ 1+  ( n1 n2 n3 -- n1 n2 n3 nlength) \ consume all entries
0            ( n1 n2 n3 nl -- n1 n2 n3 nl 0) \ lower loop parameter..
do           ( n1 n2 n3 nl 0 -- n1 n2 n3) \ loop begins
list         ( n1 n2 n3 -- n1 n2 n3 addr)
I            ( n1 n2 n3 addr -- n1 n2 n3 addr I) \ calculating address
cells        ( n1 n2 n3 addr I -- n1 n2 n3 addr Ibytes)
+            ( n1 n2 n3 addr Ibytes -- n1 n2 n3 addr1+)
!            ( n1 n2 n3 addr1+ -- n1 n2) \ storing into calculated address
loop
;
```

upload works like a charm, but then I go to use this word after

```
: sum ( n1 n2 n3 -- nsum)
upload \ initiates the array
length @  \ invokes upper limit of loop
0        \ lower limit of loop
do
list          ( -- addr)        \ addr invoked
I cells +     ( addr -- addr+)  \ offset calculated and added
@             ( addr+ -- nl)    \ registered value at address fetched
cumsum @      ( nl -- nl ncs)   \ cum sum value fetched to stack
+             ( nl ncs -- nsum) \ summation
cumsum !      ( nsum --)        \ new sum written to cumsum
loop
cumsum ?      ( -- cumsum)      \ show sum
;
```

and it returns a really long number that looks like an address, and not the sum of some list of small numbers that I add to test it with.

```
1  ok
2  ok
3  ok
sum 140313777201982  ok
```

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly, the problem is to:

1. Store all numbers on the stack into an array.
2. Sum all numbers stored in an array.

I would do something like this:

```
: upload ( ... "name" -- ) create depth dup ,  0 ?do , loop ;
: sum ( a -- n ) 0 swap @+ 0 ?do @+ rot + swap loop drop ;
```

Use like this:

```
1 2 3 4 upload array
array sum .
```

Answer (score 1):

In `UPLOAD` you execute `LIST LENGTH @ CELLS ALLOT`. `ALLOT` allocates memory at the current dictionary or data space pointer, not necessarely at the address returned by `LIST`. `ALLOT` does not consume a start address from the stack. Actually the returned address by LIST in the above code snippet is used later by `!` in your array filling loop. It's the data for the first array cell. Hence your address like number returned by `SUM`.

Best is to keep `CREATE` and `ALLOT` together. Some dictionary additions occured between the creation of LIST and executing ALLOT. Your array cells might not be where LIST is pointing.

In general variables don't consume a number from the stack. Most of the time they're automaticly initialised to `0`. So `0 VARIABLE CUMSUM` will a leave zero on the stack.
This has concequences for `DEPTH` and thus `LENGTH`, if you run or type the code in one go.
Try to avoid `DEPTH`, better is to explicitly tell array defining words how many items you want, example: 
 `CREATE LIST 3 CELLS ALLOT`

BTW running your code as is in SwiftForth, I allocate a 4 cell array right after the dictionary entree for `SUM`. I store 5 items ( `LENGTH @ 1+` in `UPLOAD` ) in the dictionary right after `LIST`, overwriting parts of the dictionary entree for `CUMSUM` ...

Lars Brinkhoff shows a nice alternative, apart from `DEPTH` that is ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was as @roelf explained. I'll just add two points of interest.

1) How could you know that something was off? When you have a problem like this, examine the memory - do a hex dump!

```
1 2 3 sum -1223205794  ok
list 32 dump 
B7175C58: 58 5C 17 B7  03 00 00 00 - 02 00 00 00  01 00 00 00  X\..............
B7175C68: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 - 5E 5C 17 B7  58 5C 17 B7  ........^\..X\..
 ok
```

You can see that the first cell of list is garbage. So maybe `upload` wasn't working so well after all!

2) Note that if you just want to add all values on the stack, you don't need to clutter the namespace with variables:

```
: sum depth 1 do + loop ;
```